# Region.IsVisible(PointF) has very slow performance for large floating point values

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, region, graphicspath

I have run into a strange performance issue, and it would be great with an explanation to the behavior I'm experiencing.

I'm using System.Drawing.Region.IsVisible(PointF) to determine if a point is inside a polygon. This usually works very well, but yesterday I noticed that the performance of the IsVisible method becomes very slow if the polygon is complex and it consists of large x- and y values.

Below is some code to reproduce the issue (and an image that shows the shape of the polygon), sorry for the large array sizes, but the polygon needs to be quite complex before the issue appears.

When calling IsVisible on the original points my machine takes 460 651 milliseconds to finish, whereas when I first divide all points by 1000, and then call the method, it takes 1 millisecond. Why I'm I seeing such a big difference in the timing? I did not think the actual values of a float would affect performance.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;

namespace PerformanceTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // Create complex polygon with large x and y values
            float[] xValues = {1.014498E+07f, 1.016254E+07f, 1.019764E+07f, 1.021519E+07f, 1.023274E+07f, 1.026785E+07f, 1.026785E+07f, 1.02854E+07f, 1.02854E+07f, 1.030295E+07f, 1.03205E+07f, 1.033805E+07f, 1.035561E+07f, 1.037316E+07f, 1.039071E+07f, 1.040826E+07f, 1.042581E+07f, 1.044337E+07f, 1.046092E+07f, 1.047847E+07f, 1.049602E+07f, 1.051357E+07f, 1.054868E+07f, 1.056623E+07f, 1.058378E+07f, 1.060133E+07f, 1.061888E+07f, 1.061888E+07f, 1.063644E+07f, 1.065399E+07f, 1.068909E+07f, 1.068909E+07f, 1.070664E+07f, 1.07242E+07f, 1.074175E+07f, 1.074175E+07f, 1.07593E+07f, 1.07593E+07f, 1.077685E+07f, 1.07944E+07f, 1.07944E+07f, 1.081196E+07f, 1.081196E+07f, 1.081196E+07f, 1.082951E+07f, 1.084706E+07f, 1.084706E+07f, 1.086461E+07f, 1.086461E+07f, 1.088216E+07f, 1.089971E+07f, 1.091727E+07f, 1.093482E+07f, 1.098747E+07f, 1.100503E+07f, 1.102258E+07f, 1.104013E+07f, 1.105768E+07f, 1.107523E+07f, 1.107523E+07f, 1.109279E+07f, 1.109279E+07f, 1.109279E+07f, 1.109279E+07f, 1.109279E+07f, 1.111034E+07f, 1.111034E+07f, 1.111034E+07f, 1.111034E+07f, 1.111034E+07f, 1.112789E+07f, 1.112789E+07f, 1.112789E+07f, 1.114544E+07f, 1.116299E+07f, 1.118054E+07f, 1.11981E+07f, 1.12332E+07f, 1.125075E+07f, 1.12683E+07f, 1.128586E+07f, 1.130341E+07f, 1.135606E+07f, 1.137361E+07f, 1.139117E+07f, 1.140872E+07f, 1.144382E+07f, 1.146137E+07f, 1.147893E+07f, 1.149648E+07f, 1.151403E+07f, 1.153158E+07f, 1.154913E+07f, 1.156669E+07f, 1.156669E+07f, 1.158424E+07f, 1.158424E+07f, 1.158424E+07f, 1.158424E+07f, 1.158424E+07f, 1.158424E+07f, 1.158424E+07f, 1.158424E+07f, 1.158424E+07f, 1.158424E+07f, 1.158424E+07f, 1.156669E+07f, 1.156669E+07f, 1.151403E+07f, 1.149648E+07f, 1.149648E+07f, 1.149648E+07f, 1.149648E+07f, 1.149648E+07f, 1.149648E+07f, 1.149648E+07f, 1.149648E+07f, 1.149648E+07f, 1.153158E+07f, 1.154913E+07f, 1.156669E+07f, 1.156669E+07f, 1.158424E+07f, 1.160179E+07f, 1.160179E+07f, 1.161934E+07f, 1.165444E+07f, 1.1672E+07f, 1.168955E+07f, 1.17071E+07f, 1.172465E+07f, 1.17422E+07f, 1.175976E+07f, 1.177731E+07f, 1.179486E+07f, 1.181241E+07f, 1.182996E+07f, 1.184752E+07f, 1.186507E+07f, 1.188262E+07f, 1.190017E+07f, 1.190017E+07f, 1.191772E+07f, 1.191772E+07f, 1.193528E+07f, 1.193528E+07f, 1.193528E+07f, 1.193528E+07f, 1.193528E+07f, 1.193528E+07f, 1.193528E+07f, 1.193528E+07f, 1.193528E+07f, 1.193528E+07f, 1.193528E+07f, 1.193528E+07f, 1.193528E+07f, 1.193528E+07f, 1.193528E+07f, 1.193528E+07f, 1.193528E+07f, 1.193528E+07f, 1.193528E+07f, 1.193528E+07f, 1.195283E+07f, 1.197038E+07f, 1.198793E+07f, 1.200548E+07f, 1.202303E+07f, 1.204059E+07f, 1.205814E+07f, 1.207569E+07f, 1.209324E+07f, 1.211079E+07f, 1.212835E+07f, 1.21459E+07f, 1.216345E+07f, 1.2181E+07f, 1.219855E+07f, 1.221611E+07f, 1.221611E+07f, 1.223366E+07f, 1.225121E+07f, 1.226876E+07f, 1.226876E+07f, 1.228631E+07f, 1.230386E+07f, 1.230386E+07f, 1.230386E+07f, 1.232142E+07f, 1.232142E+07f, 1.232142E+07f, 1.232142E+07f, 1.232142E+07f, 1.232142E+07f, 1.232142E+07f, 1.232142E+07f, 1.235652E+07f, 1.235652E+07f, 1.237407E+07f, 1.237407E+07f, 1.239162E+07f, 1.239162E+07f, 1.240918E+07f, 1.242673E+07f, 1.242673E+07f, 1.244428E+07f, 1.247938E+07f, 1.249694E+07f, 1.251449E+07f, 1.253204E+07f, 1.254959E+07f, 1.256714E+07f, 1.258469E+07f, 1.260225E+07f, 1.263735E+07f, 1.26549E+07f, 1.267245E+07f, 1.269001E+07f, 1.270756E+07f, 1.272511E+07f, 1.272511E+07f, 1.274266E+07f, 1.274266E+07f, 1.276021E+07f, 1.276021E+07f, 1.277776E+07f, 1.277776E+07f, 1.277776E+07f, 1.277776E+07f, 1.279532E+07f, 1.279532E+07f, 1.279532E+07f, 1.281287E+07f, 1.281287E+07f, 1.281287E+07f, 1.281287E+07f, 1.281287E+07f, 1.281287E+07f, 1.281287E+07f, 1.281287E+07f, 1.281287E+07f, 1.281287E+07f, 1.281287E+07f, 1.281287E+07f, 1.281287E+07f, 1.281287E+07f, 1.281287E+07f, 1.279532E+07f, 1.277776E+07f, 1.276021E+07f, 1.276021E+07f, 1.274266E+07f, 1.274266E+07f, 1.272511E+07f, 1.272511E+07f, 1.272511E+07f, 1.274266E+07f, 1.276021E+07f, 1.279532E+07f, 1.281287E+07f, 1.283042E+07f, 1.284797E+07f, 1.286552E+07f, 1.288308E+07f, 1.290063E+07f, 1.291818E+07f, 1.293573E+07f, 1.295328E+07f, 1.295328E+07f, 1.297084E+07f, 1.297084E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.300594E+07f, 1.300594E+07f, 1.302349E+07f, 1.304104E+07f, 1.305859E+07f, 1.30937E+07f, 1.311125E+07f, 1.31288E+07f, 1.314635E+07f, 1.316391E+07f, 1.318146E+07f, 1.319901E+07f, 1.321656E+07f, 1.323411E+07f, 1.325167E+07f, 1.325167E+07f, 1.326922E+07f, 1.326922E+07f, 1.328677E+07f, 1.330432E+07f, 1.330432E+07f, 1.330432E+07f, 1.332187E+07f, 1.333943E+07f, 1.335698E+07f, 1.335698E+07f, 1.337453E+07f, 1.339208E+07f, 1.340963E+07f, 1.340963E+07f, 1.342718E+07f, 1.344474E+07f, 1.346229E+07f, 1.347984E+07f, 1.349739E+07f, 1.351494E+07f, 1.355005E+07f, 1.35676E+07f, 1.36027E+07f, 1.363781E+07f, 1.367291E+07f, 1.367291E+07f, 1.370801E+07f, 1.372557E+07f, 1.376067E+07f, 1.377822E+07f, 1.381333E+07f, 1.383088E+07f, 1.384843E+07f, 1.386598E+07f, 1.390109E+07f, 1.391864E+07f, 1.391864E+07f, 1.393619E+07f, 1.395374E+07f, 1.397129E+07f, 1.398884E+07f, 1.40064E+07f, 1.402395E+07f, 1.405905E+07f, 1.409416E+07f, 1.412926E+07f, 1.414681E+07f, 1.418191E+07f, 1.419947E+07f, 1.421702E+07f, 1.423457E+07f, 1.426967E+07f, 1.430478E+07f, 1.433988E+07f, 1.435743E+07f, 1.437499E+07f, 1.439254E+07f, 1.439254E+07f, 1.442764E+07f, 1.442764E+07f, 1.444519E+07f, 1.446274E+07f, 1.446274E+07f, 1.446274E+07f, 1.446274E+07f, 1.446274E+07f, 1.446274E+07f, 1.446274E+07f, 1.446274E+07f, 1.446274E+07f, 1.446274E+07f, 1.446274E+07f, 1.444519E+07f, 1.442764E+07f, 1.441009E+07f, 1.439254E+07f, 1.437499E+07f, 1.435743E+07f, 1.433988E+07f, 1.432233E+07f, 1.430478E+07f, 1.430478E+07f, 1.426967E+07f, 1.426967E+07f, 1.423457E+07f, 1.421702E+07f, 1.418191E+07f, 1.414681E+07f, 1.412926E+07f, 1.409416E+07f, 1.405905E+07f, 1.402395E+07f, 1.40064E+07f, 1.395374E+07f, 1.393619E+07f, 1.391864E+07f, 1.390109E+07f, 1.390109E+07f, 1.388353E+07f, 1.388353E+07f, 1.388353E+07f, 1.388353E+07f, 1.388353E+07f, 1.388353E+07f, 1.388353E+07f, 1.388353E+07f, 1.388353E+07f, 1.388353E+07f, 1.390109E+07f, 1.391864E+07f, 1.393619E+07f, 1.395374E+07f, 1.398884E+07f, 1.398884E+07f, 1.40064E+07f, 1.402395E+07f, 1.402395E+07f, 1.40415E+07f, 1.405905E+07f, 1.40766E+07f, 1.412926E+07f, 1.414681E+07f, 1.416436E+07f, 1.418191E+07f, 1.419947E+07f, 1.421702E+07f, 1.423457E+07f, 1.423457E+07f, 1.423457E+07f, 1.423457E+07f, 1.423457E+07f, 1.423457E+07f, 1.423457E+07f, 1.423457E+07f, 1.423457E+07f, 1.423457E+07f, 1.423457E+07f, 1.423457E+07f, 1.423457E+07f, 1.421702E+07f, 1.419947E+07f, 1.418191E+07f, 1.416436E+07f, 1.416436E+07f, 1.412926E+07f, 1.411171E+07f, 1.409416E+07f, 1.40766E+07f, 1.405905E+07f, 1.40415E+07f, 1.402395E+07f, 1.40064E+07f, 1.397129E+07f, 1.397129E+07f, 1.395374E+07f, 1.393619E+07f, 1.393619E+07f, 1.391864E+07f, 1.391864E+07f, 1.390109E+07f, 1.388353E+07f, 1.388353E+07f, 1.386598E+07f, 1.384843E+07f, 1.383088E+07f, 1.379577E+07f, 1.376067E+07f, 1.372557E+07f, 1.370801E+07f, 1.369046E+07f, 1.365536E+07f, 1.363781E+07f, 1.362026E+07f, 1.36027E+07f, 1.358515E+07f, 1.35676E+07f, 1.35325E+07f, 1.351494E+07f, 1.349739E+07f, 1.347984E+07f, 1.346229E+07f, 1.344474E+07f, 1.339208E+07f, 1.337453E+07f, 1.335698E+07f, 1.333943E+07f, 1.332187E+07f, 1.332187E+07f, 1.330432E+07f, 1.326922E+07f, 1.325167E+07f, 1.323411E+07f, 1.321656E+07f, 1.319901E+07f, 1.316391E+07f, 1.314635E+07f, 1.31288E+07f, 1.311125E+07f, 1.307615E+07f, 1.304104E+07f, 1.302349E+07f, 1.300594E+07f, 1.300594E+07f, 1.300594E+07f, 1.300594E+07f, 1.300594E+07f, 1.300594E+07f, 1.300594E+07f, 1.302349E+07f, 1.304104E+07f, 1.307615E+07f, 1.30937E+07f, 1.311125E+07f, 1.314635E+07f, 1.316391E+07f, 1.318146E+07f, 1.319901E+07f, 1.321656E+07f, 1.323411E+07f, 1.323411E+07f, 1.323411E+07f, 1.323411E+07f, 1.325167E+07f, 1.325167E+07f, 1.325167E+07f, 1.325167E+07f, 1.325167E+07f, 1.325167E+07f, 1.325167E+07f, 1.325167E+07f, 1.325167E+07f, 1.325167E+07f, 1.325167E+07f, 1.325167E+07f, 1.325167E+07f, 1.325167E+07f, 1.323411E+07f, 1.323411E+07f, 1.321656E+07f, 1.319901E+07f, 1.318146E+07f, 1.316391E+07f, 1.314635E+07f, 1.31288E+07f, 1.305859E+07f, 1.304104E+07f, 1.298839E+07f, 1.295328E+07f, 1.291818E+07f, 1.288308E+07f, 1.286552E+07f, 1.284797E+07f, 1.283042E+07f, 1.279532E+07f, 1.277776E+07f, 1.276021E+07f, 1.272511E+07f, 1.270756E+07f, 1.269001E+07f, 1.26549E+07f, 1.263735E+07f, 1.260225E+07f, 1.258469E+07f, 1.256714E+07f, 1.256714E+07f, 1.254959E+07f, 1.253204E+07f, 1.253204E+07f, 1.253204E+07f, 1.251449E+07f, 1.251449E+07f, 1.251449E+07f, 1.251449E+07f, 1.251449E+07f, 1.249694E+07f, 1.249694E+07f, 1.249694E+07f, 1.249694E+07f, 1.247938E+07f, 1.247938E+07f, 1.246183E+07f, 1.244428E+07f, 1.240918E+07f, 1.239162E+07f, 1.235652E+07f, 1.233897E+07f, 1.230386E+07f, 1.226876E+07f, 1.225121E+07f, 1.221611E+07f, 1.219855E+07f, 1.219855E+07f, 1.2181E+07f, 1.216345E+07f, 1.216345E+07f, 1.21459E+07f, 1.21459E+07f, 1.212835E+07f, 1.212835E+07f, 1.212835E+07f, 1.212835E+07f, 1.212835E+07f, 1.211079E+07f, 1.211079E+07f, 1.211079E+07f, 1.211079E+07f, 1.211079E+07f, 1.211079E+07f, 1.211079E+07f, 1.211079E+07f, 1.211079E+07f, 1.211079E+07f, 1.211079E+07f, 1.211079E+07f, 1.211079E+07f, 1.211079E+07f, 1.211079E+07f, 1.211079E+07f, 1.211079E+07f, 1.211079E+07f, 1.211079E+07f, 1.209324E+07f, 1.207569E+07f, 1.207569E+07f, 1.204059E+07f, 1.202303E+07f, 1.200548E+07f, 1.198793E+07f, 1.197038E+07f, 1.195283E+07f, 1.193528E+07f, 1.191772E+07f, 1.190017E+07f, 1.188262E+07f, 1.186507E+07f, 1.181241E+07f, 1.181241E+07f, 1.179486E+07f, 1.177731E+07f, 1.177731E+07f, 1.177731E+07f, 1.175976E+07f, 1.175976E+07f, 1.17422E+07f, 1.17422E+07f, 1.17422E+07f, 1.17422E+07f, 1.17422E+07f, 1.17422E+07f, 1.172465E+07f, 1.172465E+07f, 1.172465E+07f, 1.172465E+07f, 1.172465E+07f, 1.172465E+07f, 1.172465E+07f, 1.172465E+07f, 1.172465E+07f, 1.172465E+07f, 1.17071E+07f, 1.168955E+07f, 1.1672E+07f, 1.163689E+07f, 1.161934E+07f, 1.160179E+07f, 1.156669E+07f, 1.154913E+07f, 1.151403E+07f, 1.149648E+07f, 1.147893E+07f, 1.146137E+07f, 1.144382E+07f, 1.144382E+07f, 1.139117E+07f, 1.139117E+07f, 1.137361E+07f, 1.137361E+07f, 1.137361E+07f, 1.137361E+07f, 1.137361E+07f, 1.137361E+07f, 1.135606E+07f, 1.135606E+07f, 1.135606E+07f, 1.135606E+07f, 1.135606E+07f, 1.135606E+07f, 1.135606E+07f, 1.135606E+07f, 1.135606E+07f, 1.135606E+07f, 1.133851E+07f, 1.133851E+07f, 1.133851E+07f, 1.133851E+07f, 1.133851E+07f, 1.130341E+07f, 1.130341E+07f, 1.128586E+07f, 1.12683E+07f, 1.125075E+07f, 1.121565E+07f, 1.116299E+07f, 1.112789E+07f, 1.107523E+07f, 1.105768E+07f, 1.102258E+07f, 1.098747E+07f, 1.095237E+07f, 1.091727E+07f, 1.089971E+07f, 1.088216E+07f, 1.086461E+07f, 1.082951E+07f, 1.081196E+07f, 1.081196E+07f, 1.07944E+07f, 1.07944E+07f, 1.077685E+07f, 1.07593E+07f, 1.07593E+07f, 1.074175E+07f, 1.074175E+07f, 1.074175E+07f, 1.074175E+07f, 1.074175E+07f, 1.074175E+07f, 1.074175E+07f, 1.074175E+07f, 1.074175E+07f, 1.07593E+07f, 1.07593E+07f, 1.077685E+07f, 1.07944E+07f, 1.07944E+07f, 1.081196E+07f, 1.082951E+07f, 1.082951E+07f, 1.086461E+07f, 1.088216E+07f, 1.089971E+07f, 1.089971E+07f, 1.091727E+07f, 1.091727E+07f, 1.091727E+07f, 1.091727E+07f, 1.091727E+07f, 1.091727E+07f, 1.089971E+07f, 1.088216E+07f, 1.082951E+07f, 1.07944E+07f, 1.07593E+07f, 1.070664E+07f, 1.068909E+07f, 1.067154E+07f, 1.065399E+07f, 1.063644E+07f, 1.061888E+07f, 1.060133E+07f, 1.058378E+07f, 1.056623E+07f, 1.054868E+07f, 1.051357E+07f, 1.049602E+07f, 1.047847E+07f, 1.046092E+07f, 1.042581E+07f, 1.039071E+07f, 1.030295E+07f, 1.026785E+07f, 1.023274E+07f, 1.019764E+07f, 1.018009E+07f, 1.016254E+07f, 1.014498E+07f, 1.010988E+07f, 1.009233E+07f, 1.007478E+07f, 1.005722E+07f, 1.003967E+07f, 1.002212E+07f, 9969464f, 9916809f, 9881705f, 9864154f, 9846602f, 9829050f, 9811497f, 9793945f, 9776394f, 9741290f, 9723738f, 9688635f, 9653531f, 9653531f, 9618427f, 9618427f, 9600875f, 9600875f, 9600875f, 9583323f, 9565771f, 9565771f, 9530667f, 9530667f, 9530667f, 9530667f, 9530667f, 9530667f, 9530667f, 9530667f, 9548219f, 9565771f, 9583323f, 9618427f, 9653531f, 9671083f, 9688635f, 9706186f, 9741290f, 9758842f, 9811497f, 9829050f, 9864154f, 9881705f, 9916809f, 9934361f, 9951913f, 9987016f, 1.000457E+07f, 1.003967E+07f, 1.005722E+07f, 1.007478E+07f, 1.010988E+07f, 1.014498E+07f, 1.016254E+07f, 1.016254E+07f, 1.018009E+07f, 1.019764E+07f, 1.021519E+07f, 1.023274E+07f, 1.023274E+07f, 1.023274E+07f, 1.023274E+07f, 1.023274E+07f, 1.023274E+07f, 1.023274E+07f, 1.023274E+07f, 1.021519E+07f, 1.019764E+07f, 1.016254E+07f, 1.014498E+07f, 1.012743E+07f, 1.009233E+07f, 1.003967E+07f, 1.000457E+07f, 9951913f, 9934361f, 9899257f, 9881705f, 9864154f, 9846602f, 9829050f, 9793945f, 9758842f, 9723738f, 9688635f, 9653531f, 9635979f, 9618427f, 9583323f, 9565771f, 9530667f, 9513116f, 9495564f, 9478012f, 9460460f, 9460460f, 9442908f, 9425357f, 9425357f, 9407805f, 9390253f, 9390253f, 9372701f, 9372701f, 9372701f, 9372701f, 9372701f, 9372701f, 9372701f, 9372701f, 9372701f, 9372701f, 9372701f, 9372701f, 9390253f, 9407805f, 9425357f, 9460460f, 9495564f, 9513116f, 9583323f, 9600875f, 9635979f, 9653531f, 9688635f, 9706186f, 9723738f, 9758842f, 9793945f, 9811497f, 9846602f};
            float[] yValues = { 7286825f, 7286825f, 7269351f, 7269351f, 7269351f, 7269351f, 7251876f, 7251876f, 7234401f, 7234401f, 7234401f, 7234401f, 7234401f, 7234401f, 7234401f, 7234401f, 7234401f, 7234401f, 7234401f, 7234401f, 7234401f, 7216927f, 7199453f, 7181979f, 7181979f, 7164504f, 7164504f, 7147029f, 7129555f, 7112081f, 7077132f, 7042183f, 7024709f, 7007235f, 6972285f, 6954811f, 6937337f, 6919863f, 6902388f, 6884913f, 6867439f, 6867439f, 6832491f, 6815016f, 6797541f, 6780067f, 6762593f, 6762593f, 6745119f, 6745119f, 6727644f, 6727644f, 6710169f, 6710169f, 6710169f, 6710169f, 6710169f, 6710169f, 6710169f, 6727644f, 6762593f, 6780067f, 6832491f, 6849965f, 6867439f, 6902388f, 6937337f, 6954811f, 6972285f, 6989760f, 7024709f, 7042183f, 7077132f, 7094607f, 7112081f, 7129555f, 7129555f, 7129555f, 7129555f, 7129555f, 7129555f, 7147029f, 7147029f, 7147029f, 7147029f, 7147029f, 7147029f, 7147029f, 7147029f, 7147029f, 7147029f, 7147029f, 7147029f, 7147029f, 7129555f, 7112081f, 7077132f, 7059657f, 7007235f, 6972285f, 6954811f, 6937337f, 6902388f, 6867439f, 6832491f, 6815016f, 6797541f, 6780067f, 6710169f, 6710169f, 6692695f, 6675221f, 6640272f, 6622797f, 6605323f, 6587849f, 6570375f, 6535425f, 6517951f, 6500477f, 6483003f, 6465528f, 6448053f, 6448053f, 6430579f, 6430579f, 6413105f, 6413105f, 6413105f, 6413105f, 6413105f, 6413105f, 6413105f, 6413105f, 6413105f, 6413105f, 6413105f, 6413105f, 6413105f, 6413105f, 6430579f, 6448053f, 6483003f, 6500477f, 6552900f, 6570375f, 6622797f, 6640272f, 6657747f, 6675221f, 6692695f, 6710169f, 6745119f, 6762593f, 6780067f, 6797541f, 6849965f, 6867439f, 6902388f, 6954811f, 6972285f, 6989760f, 7007235f, 7042183f, 7059657f, 7059657f, 7059657f, 7059657f, 7059657f, 7059657f, 7059657f, 7059657f, 7059657f, 7059657f, 7059657f, 7059657f, 7059657f, 7059657f, 7059657f, 7059657f, 7042183f, 7042183f, 7024709f, 7007235f, 6989760f, 6989760f, 6972285f, 6954811f, 6937337f, 6919863f, 6902388f, 6867439f, 6832491f, 6815016f, 6797541f, 6780067f, 6762593f, 6745119f, 6727644f, 6710169f, 6692695f, 6675221f, 6657747f, 6657747f, 6640272f, 6622797f, 6622797f, 6622797f, 6622797f, 6622797f, 6622797f, 6622797f, 6622797f, 6622797f, 6622797f, 6640272f, 6657747f, 6692695f, 6692695f, 6710169f, 6727644f, 6745119f, 6762593f, 6780067f, 6780067f, 6797541f, 6815016f, 6832491f, 6849965f, 6867439f, 6884913f, 6902388f, 6919863f, 6937337f, 6954811f, 6972285f, 6989760f, 7007235f, 7024709f, 7042183f, 7059657f, 7077132f, 7094607f, 7112081f, 7129555f, 7147029f, 7164504f, 7181979f, 7199453f, 7234401f, 7234401f, 7251876f, 7251876f, 7269351f, 7286825f, 7304299f, 7321773f, 7321773f, 7321773f, 7321773f, 7321773f, 7321773f, 7321773f, 7321773f, 7321773f, 7321773f, 7321773f, 7304299f, 7286825f, 7269351f, 7251876f, 7234401f, 7216927f, 7199453f, 7181979f, 7164504f, 7147029f, 7129555f, 7112081f, 7094607f, 7077132f, 7042183f, 7024709f, 7007235f, 6989760f, 6954811f, 6937337f, 6919863f, 6902388f, 6849965f, 6832491f, 6815016f, 6797541f, 6780067f, 6780067f, 6762593f, 6762593f, 6762593f, 6745119f, 6745119f, 6745119f, 6745119f, 6745119f, 6745119f, 6762593f, 6762593f, 6797541f, 6832491f, 6867439f, 6884913f, 6884913f, 6919863f, 6954811f, 6954811f, 6972285f, 6989760f, 7007235f, 7042183f, 7042183f, 7059657f, 7077132f, 7094607f, 7094607f, 7112081f, 7112081f, 7112081f, 7112081f, 7112081f, 7112081f, 7112081f, 7112081f, 7112081f, 7112081f, 7112081f, 7094607f, 7077132f, 7042183f, 7024709f, 7024709f, 7007235f, 6989760f, 6989760f, 6972285f, 6954811f, 6937337f, 6937337f, 6919863f, 6902388f, 6902388f, 6902388f, 6902388f, 6902388f, 6902388f, 6902388f, 6902388f, 6902388f, 6902388f, 6902388f, 6902388f, 6902388f, 6902388f, 6902388f, 6919863f, 6919863f, 6954811f, 6972285f, 6972285f, 6989760f, 7024709f, 7042183f, 7059657f, 7094607f, 7112081f, 7129555f, 7164504f, 7181979f, 7199453f, 7234401f, 7251876f, 7269351f, 7286825f, 7321773f, 7321773f, 7339248f, 7339248f, 7356723f, 7374197f, 7374197f, 7374197f, 7374197f, 7374197f, 7391671f, 7391671f, 7409145f, 7409145f, 7426620f, 7426620f, 7426620f, 7444095f, 7444095f, 7461569f, 7479043f, 7496517f, 7513992f, 7513992f, 7513992f, 7531467f, 7548941f, 7548941f, 7566415f, 7601364f, 7618839f, 7636313f, 7653787f, 7671261f, 7688736f, 7706211f, 7741159f, 7793583f, 7828531f, 7846005f, 7880955f, 7880955f, 7898429f, 7898429f, 7915903f, 7933377f, 7933377f, 7950852f, 7950852f, 7950852f, 7950852f, 7950852f, 7950852f, 7950852f, 7968327f, 7985801f, 8003275f, 8020749f, 8038224f, 8055699f, 8073173f, 8090647f, 8108121f, 8125596f, 8160545f, 8178019f, 8195493f, 8212968f, 8212968f, 8230443f, 8247917f, 8265391f, 8282865f, 8282865f, 8282865f, 8282865f, 8282865f, 8282865f, 8282865f, 8282865f, 8265391f, 8230443f, 8212968f, 8195493f, 8178019f, 8160545f, 8160545f, 8143071f, 8143071f, 8125596f, 8108121f, 8108121f, 8090647f, 8090647f, 8073173f, 8038224f, 8038224f, 8020749f, 8020749f, 8003275f, 7985801f, 7985801f, 7968327f, 7950852f, 7950852f, 7933377f, 7933377f, 7933377f, 7933377f, 7915903f, 7898429f, 7898429f, 7898429f, 7898429f, 7898429f, 7898429f, 7880955f, 7880955f, 7880955f, 7880955f, 7880955f, 7880955f, 7880955f, 7880955f, 7880955f, 7880955f, 7880955f, 7898429f, 7898429f, 7933377f, 7968327f, 7985801f, 8003275f, 8020749f, 8055699f, 8073173f, 8108121f, 8108121f, 8143071f, 8178019f, 8178019f, 8212968f, 8212968f, 8230443f, 8247917f, 8265391f, 8282865f, 8282865f, 8317815f, 8335289f, 8352763f, 8387712f, 8405186f, 8422661f, 8440134f, 8457609f, 8475084f, 8510033f, 8527506f, 8544981f, 8562456f, 8614878f, 8632353f, 8667302f, 8684777f, 8737200f, 8772149f, 8789622f, 8824572f, 8842046f, 8859521f, 8876994f, 8894469f, 8929418f, 8929418f, 8946893f, 8946893f, 8946893f, 8946893f, 8946893f, 8946893f, 8946893f, 8946893f, 8946893f, 8946893f, 8911944f, 8894469f, 8859521f, 8824572f, 8789622f, 8772149f, 8702250f, 8684777f, 8667302f, 8632353f, 8614878f, 8597405f, 8562456f, 8544981f, 8510033f, 8492558f, 8475084f, 8457609f, 8440134f, 8422661f, 8405186f, 8387712f, 8370237f, 8352763f, 8352763f, 8352763f, 8352763f, 8352763f, 8352763f, 8352763f, 8352763f, 8352763f, 8352763f, 8370237f, 8370237f, 8387712f, 8387712f, 8405186f, 8422661f, 8422661f, 8440134f, 8457609f, 8492558f, 8527506f, 8544981f, 8562456f, 8579930f, 8597405f, 8614878f, 8632353f, 8649828f, 8667302f, 8702250f, 8719725f, 8737200f, 8772149f, 8789622f, 8807097f, 8824572f, 8842046f, 8876994f, 8894469f, 8911944f, 8929418f, 8946893f, 8964366f, 8964366f, 8981841f, 8999316f, 9016790f, 9034265f, 9034265f, 9051738f, 9051738f, 9051738f, 9051738f, 9051738f, 9051738f, 9051738f, 9016790f, 8999316f, 8964366f, 8946893f, 8929418f, 8911944f, 8876994f, 8859521f, 8842046f, 8824572f, 8807097f, 8789622f, 8772149f, 8754674f, 8702250f, 8667302f, 8649828f, 8632353f, 8614878f, 8597405f, 8579930f, 8562456f, 8544981f, 8510033f, 8492558f, 8492558f, 8492558f, 8492558f, 8492558f, 8492558f, 8492558f, 8492558f, 8492558f, 8492558f, 8492558f, 8492558f, 8510033f, 8544981f, 8544981f, 8562456f, 8562456f, 8597405f, 8614878f, 8632353f, 8667302f, 8702250f, 8719725f, 8754674f, 8789622f, 8824572f, 8842046f, 8859521f, 8876994f, 8911944f, 8929418f, 8964366f, 8964366f, 8999316f, 9016790f, 9034265f, 9086688f, 9104162f, 9139110f, 9156585f, 9174060f, 9209009f, 9243957f, 9261432f, 9261432f, 9261432f, 9261432f, 9261432f, 9261432f, 9261432f, 9261432f, 9261432f, 9261432f, 9261432f, 9243957f, 9226482f, 9191534f, 9174060f, 9156585f, 9086688f, 9051738f, 9034265f, 8999316f, 8981841f, 8964366f, 8929418f, 8894469f, 8876994f, 8842046f, 8824572f, 8807097f, 8789622f, 8772149f, 8754674f, 8702250f, 8684777f, 8667302f, 8667302f, 8649828f, 8614878f, 8597405f, 8579930f, 8562456f, 8562456f, 8527506f, 8510033f, 8492558f, 8475084f, 8440134f, 8422661f, 8422661f, 8387712f, 8370237f, 8370237f, 8370237f, 8370237f, 8370237f, 8335289f, 8335289f, 8335289f, 8335289f, 8335289f, 8335289f, 8335289f, 8335289f, 8335289f, 8335289f, 8335289f, 8352763f, 8370237f, 8405186f, 8440134f, 8457609f, 8492558f, 8510033f, 8527506f, 8562456f, 8579930f, 8597405f, 8597405f, 8632353f, 8632353f, 8667302f, 8702250f, 8719725f, 8754674f, 8754674f, 8754674f, 8754674f, 8754674f, 8754674f, 8754674f, 8754674f, 8737200f, 8719725f, 8702250f, 8684777f, 8667302f, 8649828f, 8632353f, 8614878f, 8562456f, 8527506f, 8440134f, 8422661f, 8387712f, 8352763f, 8317815f, 8300340f, 8282865f, 8265391f, 8247917f, 8212968f, 8212968f, 8160545f, 8143071f, 8125596f, 8108121f, 8108121f, 8090647f, 8090647f, 8073173f, 8073173f, 8055699f, 8055699f, 8055699f, 8038224f, 8038224f, 8038224f, 8038224f, 8038224f, 8020749f, 8020749f, 8003275f, 8003275f, 7985801f, 7950852f, 7933377f, 7915903f, 7915903f, 7880955f, 7863480f, 7846005f, 7828531f, 7793583f, 7776108f, 7758633f, 7741159f, 7723685f, 7706211f, 7706211f, 7706211f, 7706211f, 7706211f, 7706211f, 7706211f, 7706211f, 7706211f, 7706211f, 7706211f, 7706211f, 7723685f, 7723685f, 7741159f, 7741159f, 7741159f, 7741159f, 7741159f, 7741159f, 7741159f, 7741159f, 7741159f, 7741159f, 7741159f, 7741159f, 7741159f, 7741159f, 7741159f, 7741159f, 7723685f, 7723685f, 7688736f, 7671261f, 7653787f, 7583889f, 7566415f, 7513992f, 7461569f, 7444095f, 7409145f, 7374197f, 7356723f, 7321773f, 7304299f, 7286825f, 7269351f, 7251876f, 7234401f, 7199453f, 7181979f, 7164504f, 7164504f, 7164504f, 7164504f, 7164504f, 7164504f, 7164504f, 7164504f, 7164504f, 7164504f, 7164504f, 7164504f, 7164504f, 7181979f, 7199453f };

            PointF[] points = xValues.Zip(yValues, (x, y) => new PointF(x, y)).ToArray();


            // Create a region with the original values 
            GraphicsPath pathWithOriginalPoints = new GraphicsPath();
            pathWithOriginalPoints.AddPolygon(points);
            Region regionFromOriginalPoints = new Region(pathWithOriginalPoints);

            // Create a region with the values divided by 1000
            GraphicsPath pathDividedBy1000 = new GraphicsPath();
            pathDividedBy1000.AddPolygon(points.Select(p => new PointF(p.X/1000f, p.Y/1000f)).ToArray());
            Region regionDividedby1000 = new Region(pathDividedBy1000);


            // Time call to Region.IsVisible(PointF)
            var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Console.WriteLine("Computing region.IsVisible for points divided by 1000:");
            regionDividedby1000.IsVisible(new PointF(0f, 0f));
            var dividedBy1000Timing = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed time: {dividedBy1000Timing} ms");

            stopwatch.Restart();
            Console.WriteLine("Computing region.IsVisible for original points");
            regionFromOriginalPoints.IsVisible(new PointF(0f, 0f));
            var originalTiming = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            Console.WriteLine($"Elapsed time: {originalTiming} ms");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Shape of the polygon]

Comment: Have a also tried to use the IsVisible(point, graphic) with a scaled graphics object? Some of those numbers get a little large fopr gdi bitmaps. Do you actually need to full precision?

Comment: No, I have not tried with a scaled graphics object. At the point in my code where this occurred I am not actually drawing anything, before it is drawn it is transformed to screen coordinates. You are correct in assuming that I do not need to use such big numbers for my calculation, I worked around it by scaling down the polygon and the point. However, I'm still curious to what might lead to the slow performance, just because the numbers in the polygon are large :)

Comment: Well, docs on Region are rather sparse. But it does make sense: If your shape (which is what Regions are) is huge, then many more spots must be checked to do the IsVisible test. I don't know but I imagine it creates some sort of bitmap with 1 bit depth to represent it. I do remember that creating a Region is a very expensive operation..

Comment: I agree that it makes sense that more spots must be checked to do the IsVisible thest if the shape is very large. But I still do not understand why it matters how large the actual x and y values of the shape are. The same complex shape, with equally many points, takes almost no time to compute if the values of the shape are divided by 1000.

Comment: _The same complex shape, with equally many points,..if the values of the shape are divided by 1000_ But then there will be not equally many but 1000*1000 as many points in the shape. At lest that's what I figure. Maybe Region works differently, though. Maybe it tests by creating a list of rectangles to aproximate the path. Here too there will probably be many many more used..

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm guess my sentence was a bit ambiguous. What I mean is that I divide the *values* of the shape, but the number of points is still the same. For example, instead of a point being (10000, 5000), the point becomes (10, 5). This is what I find strange, that dividing the values of each point makes the calculation much faster.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TLTR**

The time it takes to do one `Region.IsVisible(Point)` call doesn't depend on the number of points at all. Instead it depends on the **number of rectangles** it takes to fully and precisely **cover the region**. Which depends on..:

- the shapes those points describe and usually
- the size of the shape.

Example 1: A rectangular region has four points and it always takes **one rectangle** to cover it. This would not change if you would add a large number of points as long as they all lie on the sides of the rectangle!

Example 2: A circular region also (!) has four points <sub>(**)**</sub> but the number of rectangles you need to cover it fully **depends on the diameter of that circle. See the graphics at the bottom!

---

**Full Story**

[`Region`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.region%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not what I would call a 'well-documented' class.

You can see that the inner working seems to rely on the [`RegionData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.regiondata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which can can accessed by calling `var RData = your Region.GetRegionData()`.

Here the very same holds: Not well-documented, to say the least. Maybe I just can't find it, but there seems to be no info on how those bytes are structured..

<sub>(The numbers below suggest that each point needed takes 1 byte as a type indicator plus 2+4 bytes for the two float coordinates. This would be like the `PathPoints&PathTypes` in the `GraphicsPath`.  In your example with 924+1 points and 1+2*4 bytes this makes up 8325 bytes; another 27 bytes are there; 8 could hold the scaling..)</sub>

One thing is interesting though: Looking into the `RegionData` from **both** of your `Regions` one can easily see that they have the **same** size..: `8352`. This is an indication that the `RegionData` are not directly relevant for the additional time anyway..

But there is **another**, somewhat equally mysterious, read: ill-documented call: `GetRegionScans`. MSDN says this about it:

> Returns an array of RectangleF structures that approximate this Region
>   after the specified matrix transformation is applied.

**First** lets see what happens if we pull out thoses 'scans'  for both of your Regions:

```
Matrix M = new Matrix();

var scans1 = regionFromOriginalPoints.GetRegionScans(M);
var scans2 = regionDividedby1000.GetRegionScans(M);
```

I use the simple identity matrix (*), i.e. no transformation and these are the reults:

```
scans1.Length = 5.960.690
scans2.Length = 5.956
```

So it creates **1000 times more** rectangles to approximate the `Region`, and, lo and behold for doing so it also takes a lot of time..:

This is not really surprising: The unscaled path covers a huge area and to approximate it I would expect many more rectangles are needed. I don't know how the approximation works, but it might decide that, even though `RectangleF` are returned,  no rectangle with any side being less than 1 pixel is needed.

**So I conclude that the `IsVisible` call internally needs to create those approximation rectangles** and it needs enough of them to **cover every full pixel** inside the region. (Note that `Region` does not support partial/anti-aliased pixels!)  The larger the region's bounds the more pixels fit in and the longer the scanning process takes.

I also assume that it is strictly the scanning process that eats up the time.

**Next**: Doing a `RectangleF.Contains(Point)` should be extremely fast, even for a million calls. Let's see; when I measure this:

```
int hits = 0;
PointF pt = new PointF(123.456f, 789.012f);
foreach (RectangleF r in scans1) if (r.Contains(pt)) hits++;
```

..it takes only  `42ms` to complete.  So once you have **cached** the scan rectangles you can easily do a lot of hit tests on them **instead** of doing separate `IsVisible` calls..

Here is a summary of the numbers :

> Your original path:
>
> number of polygon points = 924
>   regionData1.Length = 8.352
>   scans1.Length = 5.960.690 
>   Elapsed time1: 453.187 ms
>
> The path scaled down by 1000:
>
> number of polygon points = 924
>   regionData2.Length = 8.352
>   scans2.Length= 5.956
>   Elapsed time2: 2 ms
>
> Elapsed time for full set of scans: 41 ms

---

**Finally**: To better understand the scan rectangles I approximated a circle with alternating colors:

```
for (int i = 0; i < scans.Length; i++)
     g.FillRectangle(i%2 == 0 ? Brushes.ForestGreen : Brushes.Salmon, scans[i]);
```

[image]

You can see that at the top and bottom every row is one rectangle because here the curve is flat and the x coordinates move outward quickly. The closer we get to the middle the larger (i..e. taller) the rectangles can get... So we can see that the approximation strictly follows the **rows**..

This holds true even if the bounding rectangle is taller than wide and, using the columns, one might do with fewer rectangles:

[image]

Here **both** ellipses (`222x111` and `111x222`) are approximated with `85` **horizontal** stripes. That is less than the circle because of the different curvature..

---

(*) - **We have skipped over the `Matrix`**; but it could be used to modify the result by either scaling the data up or down. **The circle has a `Height` of `222` pixels and it takes `135` scan rectangles to approximate it.** If we scale up the `Matrix`, (i.e. the `Graphics` object used to represent the `Region`): `m.Scale(10,10);` it takes `1315` scan rectangles to cover the upscaled circle.

So a matrix scaled down by `0.001f` could be used instead of scaling your data points; but it would test only the scaled down version and will likely either miss pixels around the borders or include wrong ones. So best use only the correct scale you actually need..

<sub>(* *) Note that the circular `GraphicsPath` does have **13** `PathPoints`; but these are really just four real points (plus the 1st one repeated to close the figure) plus **two control points** in between each pair of points; so 5 + 4*2 = 13. Also note that **any** line in a `GraphicsPath` is **either straight or a bezier curve.** This includes arcs, ellipses and circles!</sub>

Comment: Great investigation! Makes sense that the scanning process takes a lot longer for many more rectangles. I'm however not sure I understand your reasoning for why you would need more rectangles for the larger shape. Shouldn't it be possible to just scale the rectangles as well?

Comment: But you need to follow the curves and include every full pixel! Try to imagine doing the scanning process for a circle: if it is a small as 3x3 the number of rectangles you need can be as low as 1-3; not make it larger, say, 30x30 and approximate it by rectangles: You will need at least one for every or every second row, so it will take 15-30 rectangles.. I tried it and for a circle __it does take one rectangle per row__.

Comment: I see, makes sense! Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: See the illustration I appended!

Answer (score 6):

We've have been struggling with the same issue: with a 50k points polygon it tooks 45 seconds to build the rectangles behind the IsVisible() method. We tried to cache this data, but finally we had over 1 millions rectangles; with multiple regions we had hundreds megabytes of data to cache.

Finally we moved to the PNPoly algorithm, that takes just few ms:

https://wrf.ecse.rpi.edu/Research/Short_Notes/pnpoly.html

Here the c# version:

```
    public bool IsVisible(Point p, List<Point> points)
    {
        int i, j = points.Count - 1;
        bool isVisible = false;
        for (i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
        {
            if (points[i].Y < p.Y && points[j].Y >= p.Y 
                || points[j].Y < p.Y && points[i].Y >= p.Y)
            {
                if (points[i].X + (p.Y - points[i].Y) / (points[j].Y - points[i].Y) 
                    * (points[j].X - points[i].X) < p.X)
                {
                    isVisible = !isVisible;
                }
            }
            j = i;
        }
        return isVisible;
    }
```