# Create combined Region for UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, region

I want my UserControl to automatically update its Region property. I want it to be a combination of child controls' regions merged together.

Here what I have so far:

```
protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSizeChanged(e);

    Region region = new Region(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, Size.Empty));

    foreach (Control control in Controls)
    {
        if (control.Region != null)
            region.Union(control.Region);
        else
            region.Union(control.Bounds);
    }

    Region = region;
    Invalidate();
}
```

Problem is that it does not work: Line `region.Union(control.Region);` must be changed because Region does not include information about left and top offset of the control.

What can I do?

Comment: How do you create the Regions of the controls? By a GraphicsPath? In one go or progressively?

Comment: @Taw - Yes, using GraphicsPath in one go. Does it matter?

Comment: You can store those GraphicsPaths, maybe in the Tags and then use them for the Union. You can move them with a Matrix.

Comment: @TaW - I am wondering if GetRegionScans method could be helpful in this situation?

Comment: Yes it could but, depending on the size of the controls it might get really slow. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43139118/region-isvisiblepointf-has-very-slow-performance-for-large-floating-point-valu/43180365?s=1|0.1496#43180365) for a discussion!

Comment: @TaW - You are right - too slow. Is it possible to move region using matrix transformation? I mean get region data while applying matrix transformation and then feed it back to region constructor?

Comment: You need to move the GraphicsPath. You can store it in a Property of the child Controls. Seems to work here- I'll post wat I have if you want to see it..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150494/discussion-between-walruz-and-taw).

Comment: @TaW - I didn't want child controls to be special. I was trying to avoid that. I want my UserControl to work with just any control without requiring extra properties or stored data in tag field.

Comment: Well in that case I guess you need to go for the GetRegionScans method.. But of course any control does have a Tag, so when you set the Region you could make of it.

Comment: @TaW - thank you for your help! I believe you saved me some time.

Comment: No problem, a pleasure tackling an interesting task. You may want ot check the code examples in my answer post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a choice of **either** going for the `Rectangles` that actually make up a `Region`. You can get them via `GetRegionScans`. You can see them in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43139118/region-isvisiblepointf-has-very-slow-performance-for-large-floating-point-valu/43180365?s=1|0.1496#43180365).

**Or** of using the `GraphicsPaths` your child controls' `Regions` originate from..

In both methods you can move the controls' region data by its location: Either by offsetting each rectangle or by translating the whole graphicspath.

**Here** is a code example for the 1st method:

```
if (control.Region != null)
{
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();  // default, unscaled screen-resolution matrix
    var rex = control.Region.GetRegionScans(matrix);  // get rectangles
    foreach (var r in rex)   // use each of them
    {
        r.Offset(control.Location);  //  move by the location offsets
        region.Union(r);
    }
else
{
    region.Union(control.Bounds);
}
```

The problem is that this tends to get slower and slower with the 'vertical' **size** and the **complexity** of the `Region` shapes..

The **other** way is to keep track of the `GraphicsPaths` of the child controls.

Assuming a class `PathControl` with a control property

```
public GraphicsPath path { get; set; }
```

You could change the loop maybe to this:

```
foreach (Control control in Controls)
{
    if (control is PathControl)
    {
        // use a clone, so the original path won't be changed!
        GraphicsPath gp = (GraphicsPath)(control as PathControl).path.Clone();

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.Translate(control.Left, control.Top);
        gp.Transform(matrix);  // here we move by the location offsets

        region.Union(gp);
    else
    {
        region.Union(control.Bounds);
    }
}
```