# Test for rectangle-line intersection

Tags: c#, winforms, intersection

I am trying to see if an imagebox interacts with an e graphics line. 
my current code:

```
e.Graphics.DrawLine(SystemPens.ButtonShadow, a, b);

if (pictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(e.GraphicsLine.Bounds))
{
    dead();
}
```

I am unsure how to do this.

Comment: You need to think how whould you do that using a pencil a paper and some geometry. Then write your solution with code.

Comment: What is imagebox? No such control in Winforms! -  Always call things by their __right__ name!

Answer (score 2):

To test for intersection of a rectangle and a line you can either use one of the many methods from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_clipping) article or use a GDI+ trick involving `GraphicsPaths` and `Regions`..:

```
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
..

bool Intersects(Point a, Point b, Rectangle r)
{
    if (Math.Min(a.X, b.X) > r.Right)  return false;   // *
    if (Math.Max(a.X, b.X) < r.Left)   return false;   // *
    if (Math.Min(a.Y, b.Y) > r.Bottom) return false;   // *
    if (Math.Max(a.Y, b.Y) < r.Top)    return false;   // *

    if (r.Contains(a)) return true;   // **
    if (r.Contains(b)) return true;   // **

    using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Empty, 0.5f))
    using (Region reg = new Region(r))
    using (Graphics g = CreateGraphics())
    {
        gp.AddLine(a,b);
        gp.Widen(pen);   // we need to widen the line path just a little
        reg.Intersect(gp);
        if (reg.IsEmpty(g)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is a small test result:

[image]

Since `Region.IsEmpty` is probably not very fast I have prepended the call with a few trivial tests for better speed. For a discussion of performance issues with Region [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43139118/region-isvisiblepointf-has-very-slow-performance-for-large-floating-point-valu/43180365#43180365). From this I guess one can conclude that testing with a simple rectangle will in fact still be reasonably fast..

For a truely fast test you may need to implement a real clipping method. [This looks nice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Sutherland_algorithm)..

But the GDI+ trick with the region has one big advantage over the analytical methods: I will work with any shapes you can put into a `GraphicsPath`, including circles, ellipes, polygons, all sorts of combinations and also complex tracing paths. And since the [`Region`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.region_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) supports all set operations, your imagination is the limit..

This allows you to test complex shapes of spaceships or monsters; and with a few extra tricks you can even test rotated shapes.

Note that if you go for testing complex shapes you will want to:

- pass in the `GraphicsPath`
- use its bounding rectangle (`gp.GetBounds()`) for the first four tests (*)
- remove the other two tests (**) since the bounding rectangle will not work now; in fact they only work with rectangles; I had to remove them for the following ellipse demo.

Here is the same example, simply replacing the rectangle with an ellipse:

[image]

Comment: That is not actually correct. Or maybe it is not correct in many cases. You are just taking a rect with the line being the diagonal. There is too much area in this rect that the picbox intersects but not with the actuall line.

Comment: Take a look at this: [Line clipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_clipping). There are `C` and `C++` implementations for the main algorithms which can be easily translated to `C#`.

Comment: @Jim : Well, you are right if he want to test the line intersecting the rectangle. He talked about the line's bounds, though. But I guess you are right about what he wants..

Comment: I didn't know the region solution. I always used lines equations and some complex staff in the past. I am going to test how fast it is. Nice solution though! +1

Comment: Yeah, well it is cheating in a way. Not sure about speed; I think it'll depend on sizes, so it may be not so good performance-wise for large rectangles..

Comment: Sadly the region doesn't work. It is exactly the same as the rectangle with the line as a diagonal, your first method. Too good to be true.

Comment: @γηράσκω: Interesting. We have to widen the line path a little to make it work. I didn't know that, always worked with closed figures with areas before, I guess. I have updated the answer with examples, removed the original part and added notes on a few pros and cons..

Comment: I don't know why but i really stack to this problem. Your solution works great! I tested the speed and for 1200 lines: *time = ~30 millisecs*. I then search for a faster method and i found the jackpot. *Andre LaMothe's code from Tricks of the Windows Game Programming Gurus*. It checks if two line segments intersect. So i checked the 1200 lines with all 4 line segments of the rectangle. The results were amazing: *~200microsecs or better 0.2 millisecs!!!*

Comment: Well, why not post the code? A really good solution for strict line-rectangle testing is surely welcome. I wanted to implement one but got distracted.. And ~100x is very nice. Btw: The speed of the region version totally depends on the data, even with a rectangle it will depend on the length of the line; yours should be completely data-independent.

Comment: @TaW I guess we do the hard work and the op doesn't give a sh..!

Comment: Well, now there's a more generic, recyclable GraphicsPath solution and @γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε has a specialized speedy solution. If the OP doesn't give a sh... about it, his loss.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. The original code was in C and i translated to vb.net. The code works with a line and a rectangle.

[image]

```
'//min_clip_x is the distance of the left side of rect
'//min_clip_y is the distance of the upper side of rect
'//max_clip_x is the distance of the right side of rect
'//min_clip_y is the distance of the down side of rect

Private Function Clip_Line(ByVal x1 As Integer, ByVal y1 As Integer, ByVal x2 As Integer, ByVal y2 As Integer,
                             ByVal min_clip_x As Integer, ByVal max_clip_x As Integer, ByVal min_clip_y As Integer,
                             ByVal max_clip_y As Integer) As Boolean

    Const CLIP_CODE_C As Integer = 0
    Const CLIP_CODE_N As Integer = 8
    Const CLIP_CODE_S As Integer = 4
    Const CLIP_CODE_E As Integer = 2
    Const CLIP_CODE_W As Integer = 1
    Const CLIP_CODE_NE As Integer = 10
    Const CLIP_CODE_SE As Integer = 6
    Const CLIP_CODE_NW As Integer = 9
    Const CLIP_CODE_SW As Integer = 5

    Dim p1_code As Integer = 0
    Dim p2_code As Integer = 0
    Dim xc1, yc1, xc2, yc2 As Integer

    xc1 = x1
    yc1 = y1
    xc2 = x2
    yc2 = y2

    '//determine codes for p1 And p2
    If y1 < min_clip_y Then
        p1_code = p1_code Or CLIP_CODE_N
    Else
        If y1 > max_clip_y Then
            p1_code = p1_code Or CLIP_CODE_S
        End If
    End If

    If (x1 < min_clip_x) Then
        p1_code = p1_code Or CLIP_CODE_W
    Else
        If (x1 > max_clip_x) Then
            p1_code = p1_code Or CLIP_CODE_E
        End If
    End If

    If (y2 < min_clip_y) Then
        p2_code = p2_code Or CLIP_CODE_N
    Else
        If (y2 > max_clip_y) Then
            p2_code = p2_code Or CLIP_CODE_S
        End If
    End If

    If (x2 < min_clip_x) Then
        p2_code = p2_code Or CLIP_CODE_W
    Else
        If (x2 > max_clip_x) Then
            p2_code = p2_code Or CLIP_CODE_E
        End If
    End If

    '//try And trivially reject
    If CBool(p1_code And p2_code) Then
        Return False
    End If

    '//test for totally visible, if so leave points untouched
    If (p1_code = 0 And p2_code = 0) Then
        Return True
    End If

    '//determine end clip point for p1
    Select Case p1_code
        Case CLIP_CODE_C
            Exit Select
        Case CLIP_CODE_N
            yc1 = min_clip_y
            xc1 = CInt(x1 + 0.5 + (min_clip_y - y1) * (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1))

            Exit Select
        Case CLIP_CODE_S
            yc1 = max_clip_y
            xc1 = CInt(x1 + 0.5 + (max_clip_y - y1) * (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1))

            Exit Select
        Case CLIP_CODE_W
            xc1 = min_clip_x
            yc1 = CInt(y1 + 0.5 + (min_clip_x - x1) * (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1))

            Exit Select
        Case CLIP_CODE_E
            xc1 = max_clip_x
            yc1 = CInt(y1 + 0.5 + (max_clip_x - x1) * (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1))

            Exit Select
        Case CLIP_CODE_NE
            '//north hline intersection
            yc1 = min_clip_y
            xc1 = CInt(x1 + 0.5 + (min_clip_y - y1) * (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1))
            '//test if intersection Is valid,
            '//if so then done, else compute next
            If (xc1 < min_clip_x) Or (xc1 > max_clip_x) Then
                '//east vline intersection
                xc1 = max_clip_x
                yc1 = CInt(y1 + 0.5 + (max_clip_x - x1) * (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1))
            End If

            Exit Select
        Case CLIP_CODE_SE
            '//south hline intersection
            yc1 = max_clip_y
            xc1 = CInt(x1 + 0.5 + (max_clip_y - y1) * (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1))
            '//test if intersection Is valid,
            '//if so then done, else compute next
            If (xc1 < min_clip_x) Or (xc1 > max_clip_x) Then
                '//east vline intersection
                xc1 = max_clip_x
                yc1 = CInt(y1 + 0.5 + (max_clip_x - x1) * (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1))
            End If

            Exit Select
        Case CLIP_CODE_NW
            '//north hline intersection
            yc1 = min_clip_y
            xc1 = CInt(x1 + 0.5 + (min_clip_y - y1) * (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1))
            '//test if intersection Is valid,
            '//if so then done, else compute next
            If (xc1 < min_clip_x) Or (xc1 > max_clip_x) Then
                xc1 = min_clip_x
                yc1 = CInt(y1 + 0.5 + (min_clip_x - x1) * (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1))
            End If

            Exit Select
        Case CLIP_CODE_SW
            '//south hline intersection
            yc1 = max_clip_y
            xc1 = CInt(x1 + 0.5 + (max_clip_y - y1) * (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1))
            '//test if intersection Is valid,
            '//if so then done, else compute next
            If (xc1 < min_clip_x) Or (xc1 > max_clip_x) Then
                xc1 = min_clip_x
                yc1 = CInt(CDbl(y1) + 0.5 + CDbl(min_clip_x - x1) * CDbl(y2 - y1) / CDbl(x2 - x1))
            End If

            Exit Select
        Case Else
            Exit Select
    End Select

    '//determine end clip point for p2
    Select Case p2_code
        Case CLIP_CODE_C
            Exit Select
        Case CLIP_CODE_N
            yc2 = min_clip_y
            xc2 = CInt(x2 + (min_clip_y - y2) * (x1 - x2) / (y1 - y2))

            Exit Select
        Case CLIP_CODE_S
            yc2 = max_clip_y
            xc2 = CInt(x2 + (max_clip_y - y2) * (x1 - x2) / (y1 - y2))

            Exit Select
        Case CLIP_CODE_W
            xc2 = min_clip_x
            yc2 = CInt(y2 + (min_clip_x - x2) * (y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2))

            Exit Select
        Case CLIP_CODE_E
            xc2 = max_clip_x
            yc2 = CInt(y2 + (max_clip_x - x2) * (y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2))

            Exit Select
        Case CLIP_CODE_NE
            '//north hline intersection
            yc2 = min_clip_y
            xc2 = CInt(x2 + 0.5 + (min_clip_y - y2) * (x1 - x2) / (y1 - y2))
            '//test if intersection Is valid,
            '//if so then done, else compute next
            If (xc2 < min_clip_x) Or (xc2 > max_clip_x) Then
                '//east vline intersection
                xc2 = max_clip_x
                yc2 = CInt(y2 + 0.5 + (max_clip_x - x2) * (y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2))
            End If

            Exit Select
        Case CLIP_CODE_SE
            '//south hline intersection
            yc2 = max_clip_y
            xc2 = CInt(x2 + 0.5 + (max_clip_y - y2) * (x1 - x2) / (y1 - y2))
            '//test if intersection Is valid,
            '//if so then done, else compute next
            If (xc2 < min_clip_x) Or (xc2 > max_clip_x) Then
                '//east vline intersection
                xc2 = max_clip_x
                yc2 = CInt(y2 + 0.5 + (max_clip_x - x2) * (y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2))
            End If

            Exit Select
        Case CLIP_CODE_NW
            '//north hline intersection
            yc2 = min_clip_y
            xc2 = CInt(x2 + 0.5 + (min_clip_y - y2) * (x1 - x2) / (y1 - y2))
            '//test if intersection Is valid,
            '//if so then done, else compute next
            If (xc2 < min_clip_x) Or (xc2 > max_clip_x) Then
                xc2 = min_clip_x
                yc2 = CInt(y2 + 0.5 + (min_clip_x - x2) * (y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2))
            End If

            Exit Select
        Case CLIP_CODE_SW
            '//south hline intersection
            yc2 = max_clip_y
            xc2 = CInt(x2 + 0.5 + (max_clip_y - y2) * (x1 - x2) / (y1 - y2))
            '//test if intersection Is valid,
            '//if so then done, else compute next
            If (xc2 < min_clip_x) Or (xc2 > max_clip_x) Then
                xc2 = min_clip_x
                yc2 = CInt(y2 + 0.5 + (min_clip_x - x2) * (y1 - y2) / (x1 - x2))
            End If

            Exit Select
        Case Else
            Exit Select
    End Select

    '//do bounds check
    If (xc1 < min_clip_x) Or (xc1 > max_clip_x) Or (yc1 < min_clip_y) Or (yc1 > max_clip_y) Or
        (xc2 < min_clip_x) Or (xc2 > max_clip_x) Or (yc2 < min_clip_y) Or (yc2 > max_clip_y) Then

        Return False '//no collision
    End If

    Return True '//collision
End Function
```